# Autocomplete search field with Amazon API or other. NodeJS JavaScript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, autocomplete

I have been trying to configure this NodeJS module: [Amazon-Autocomplete](http://carlosroso.com/amazon-autocomplete#usage) but I'm not sure how to wire it up. The documentation shows an example set up but when I run node and type in the search field I get an error:

> addWordToCustomPanel is undefined.

I tried to implement it myself using the link the author used and using this as a guideline [How to get autocomplete](https://simplestepscode.com/autocomplete-data-tutorial/) but I ran into this error:

> Failed to load
>   http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=b:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:XXXX' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Is it possible to get autocomplete data from sites like Google and Amazon or should I just work on creating my own small local database?

Comment: Can you add some code showing what you did?

Comment: Thank for responding! 

Plunker link to my setup for Amazon Autocomplete: http://plnkr.co/edit/w8NL3ktUXnvZ75Kdjutd?p=catalogue